# How to retain the column structure of a Spark Dataframe following a map operation on rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to apply a function to each row of a Spark DataFrame, as in the example.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq((1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
df.show()
```

which yields

```
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  0|
|  0|  0|  1|
|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+
```

Suppose I want to do something to the values in each row, for example changing 0 to 5.

```
val b = df.map(row => row.toSeq.map(x => x match{
    case 0 => 5
    case x: Int => x
}))

b.show()
```

```
+---------+
|    value|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 5]|
|[5, 5, 1]|
|[5, 5, 5]|
+---------+
```

The function worked, but I now have one column whose entries are Lists, instead of 3 columns of Ints. I would like my named columns back.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted a question that got 3 interesting answers. This would never happen on Cross-Validated.

Comment: Upvoted - indeed it happens often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do it here are some:

```
df.map(row => {
      val size = row.size
      var seq: Seq[Int] = Seq.empty[Int]
      for (a <- 0 to size - 1) {
        val value: Int = row(a).asInstanceOf[Int]
        val newVal: Int = value match {
          case 0 =>
            5
          case _ =>
            value
        }
        seq = seq :+ newVal
      }
      Row.fromSeq(seq)
    })(RowEncoder.apply(df.schema))
```

```
 val columns = df.columns
    df.select(
        columns.map(c => when(col(c) === 0, 5).otherwise(col(c)).as(c)): _*)
      .show()
```

```
def fun: (Int => Int) = { x =>
      if (x == 0) 5 else x
    }
    val function = udf(fun)
    df.select(function(col("x")).as("x"),
              function(col("y")).as("y"),
              function(col("z")).as("z"))
      .show()
```

```
def checkZero(a: Int): Int = if (a == 0) 5 else a

      df.map {
        case Row(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) =>
          Row(checkZero(a), checkZero(b), checkZero(c))
      } { RowEncoder.apply(df.schema) }
      .show()
```

Comment: These are all great answers, but I have accepted this one because the first solution generalizes better to the case where the row is transformed in more complicated ways than in my toy example.

Answer (score 4):

You can define an UDF to apply this substitution. For example:

```
def subsDef(k: Int): Int = if(k==0) 5  else k
val subs = udf[Int, Int](subsDef)
```

Then you can apply the UDF to a specific column or, if you desire, to every columns of the DF:

```
// to a single column, for example "x"
df = df.withColumn("x", subs(col("x")))
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  0|
|  5|  0|  1|
|  5|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+



// to every columns of DF
df.columns.foreach(c => {
      df = df.withColumn(c, subs(col(c)))
    })
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  5|
|  5|  5|  1|
|  5|  5|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than transforming the DataFrame row-wise, consider using built-in Spark API function `when/otherwise`, as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq((1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0)).toDF("x", "y", "z")

val vFrom = 0
val vTo = 5

val cols = df.columns  // Filter for specific columns if necessary

df.select( cols.map( c => 
    when(col(c) === vFrom, vTo).otherwise(col(c)).as(c)
  ): _*
).show
// +---+---+---+
// |  x|  y|  z|
// +---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  5|
// |  5|  5|  1|
// |  5|  5|  5|
// +---+---+---+
```

Comment: As always a nice answer.